# jquery add a new class based on checking is not working

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery for ckeck a condition and add a new class based on checking.here I checking the dropdown selected text is "select" or else. here is my code

```
 $(".viewmore").live('click',function(event){
   var str=$(this).parents('.box01').find(".color").children("option").filter(":selected").text()
   if(str=='select'){

   $(this).addClass('valg');
   }
```

but it no enter in to the checking what is the problem any anwser?

Comment: do not use `live` use `on` instead

Answer (score 1):

Use "change" instead of "click" to get the value after it's been altered.

Also use ".on" instead of ".live" for current versions of jquery - http://api.jquery.com/on

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".viewmore").on('click', function (event) {
    var str = $(this).parents('.box01').find(".color option:selected").text();
    if (str == 'select') {
        $(this).addClass('valg');
    }
});
```

Comment: $(".viewmore").live('click',function(event){
    var str=$(this).parents('.box01').find(".color").children("option").filter(":selected").text();
    alert(str);

here i getting the selected text in alert,but the checking not working.what is the problem>???